# Make OTA work with Arduino Uno Wifi

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno-wifi

I just bought a Arduino Uni Wifi Rev. 2, with the itention of doing over the air uploads to the devices.

By reading the official [Gettings started with the Arduino Uno Wifi](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUnoWiFi) guide, I thought the process was just to power the devices, connect to the SSID, then browse to it's IP and set it up.

But it seems like this is not the case, and that others have made this same mistake. This Arduino device doesn't create network by default, we have to upload a sketch that connects to our wifi.

So I have two questions.

1. **What Arduino board are they referencing in the guide linked above, that we can just connect to out of the box?**
2. **How can I get OTA support for my particular board?**

Comment: have you gone through this? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUnoWiFi

Comment: @SimSon Yes. That's the article I linked to in my post. It's only for Arduino Uno Rev. 1 it looks like.

Answer (score 3):

> What Arduino board are they referencing in the guide linked above, that we can just connect to out of the box?

[The first Uno WiFi](https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/wiki) was made in 2016 by arduino.org. It is retired and not available in stores.

> How can I get OTA support for my particular board?

The OTA support for Uno WiFi Rev. 2 is ready or almost ready, but the required additions are not merged in GitHub firmware and library repository even if they wait some months now. It looks like Arduino focuses on something else.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have a link to the Github issue/pull request for that feature, so that I can follow it?

Comment: As far as I understand, it should be possible to upload a sketch to the arduino over USB, that connects it to your wifi, so that it then can support OTA uploads. Do you have any insight into that?

Comment: not for Uno WiFi Rev 2. for many others https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA

Comment: and plans for Uno WiFi Rev 2. https://github.com/arduino/nina-fw/issues/36

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/retired/getting-started-guides/ArduinoUnoWiFi

Comment: @Bruno that is for Uno WiFi Developer Edition, not for Uno WiFi Rev2