# Uno Wifi Rev2 - sending program via WIFI

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, wifi, spi

My new Uno wifi rev2 just arrived and I have one problem.  At the beggining I connected my board via USB and tested with example blink program from WifiNiNA and It worked fine.  When program is runned and I plug in DC power suply and take off USB, my program is still working. And here is my problem. I'm wondering how I can send program/sketch to my arduino without usb just through WIFI. Is it possible? How I can do it?

Comment: two different unrelated questions ... please delete the one about the RGB LED and post separately

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70774/make-ota-work-with-arduino-uno-wifi

Comment: sad is, almost a year later the answer there is still valid. while there is a progress they still didn't publish the OTA update for Uno WiFi Rev 2.